# passing integer as an argument and interpreting the integer as bits in the method in java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I want to write a method where the argument of the method is an int, possible values are 1 -8.
And in the method i have 4 booleans, whose value i have to set as the corresponding bit value of the integer.

```
method(int x){
   bool1 = value at the first bit, 0 = false, 1 = true;
   bool2 = value at the second bit, 0 = false, 1 = true;
   bool3 = value at the third bit, 0 = false, 1 = true;
   bool4 = value at the last bit, 0 = false, 1 = true;
}
```

So, if have to set bool1 = false, bool2 = true, bool3 = false, bool4 = true,
I would pass "5" as the argument to the method (which translates to binary 0101).

I dont know how to do that in Java(syntax wise and optimal code wise).

Thanks in advance. Not a homework

Comment: What do you mean by _first bit_ ? Most- or least significant?

Comment: First Google result for "Java bit operator": http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: most, i mean 5 = 0101 = false, true, false, true..

Comment: So you want values 0001 to 1000. so the first bit will only be set if the values is 8.

Comment: what i did not know was how to set the boolean. I think the two answers below solve my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specification translates to:

```
void method(int x) {
   boolean bool1 = (x & 8) > 0;
   boolean bool2 = (x & 4) > 0;
   boolean bool3 = (x & 2) > 0;
   boolean bool4 = (x & 1) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a mask and the bitwise AND operator to check if each bit is set.

```
//0x8 is 1000 in binary, if the correctbit is set in x then x & 0x8 will
//equal 0x8, otherwise it will be 0.
bool1 = (0x8 & x) != 0;
//Do the same for the other bits, with the correct masks.
bool2 = (0x4 & x) != 0;
bool3 = (0x2 & x) != 0;
bool4 = (0x1 & x) != 0;
```